# Conncetion to multiple shemas in PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How can I connect to multiple shemas in PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy?

When I use create_engine function, I can connect only to default public shema but in my case I need to push a data to public shema and my new created shema in the single database

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')
```

Comment: You don't "connect to a schema". You connect to a database, then *use* different schemas in that database. Can't you simply prefix your tables? e.g. `my_schema.some_table` when referencing them? Or change the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for that user?

Comment: I'm working on exisitng project and I'm looking for solutions without deeply changes.  I just want to change the use of `public` shema in application to `myschema`, the best in one place in code. That's why I was thinking about `create_engine` function

Comment: If you don't have the same table name twice in both schemas, you can simply change the search_path for the user: `alter user scott set search_path = public, myschema;` Then you don't need to change anything in your application.

Comment: `myschema` is cloned from my `public`. Both of them have the same structure. I found something like this: `connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})` but it's probably the identical solution to yours

Comment: It will work well probalby, when I will create two users and define search_path for each of them